# DrawableCompat.setTint() no longer working with appcompat-v7 23.2.1

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-appcompat

Setting the tint was previously working in 23.2.0. When I change the version to 23.2.1, the following codes no longer tints my ImageViews.

I have a list of Image view defined as

```
List<ImageView> statusStage = new ArrayList<>();
```

and I update the image tint using the method below.

```
public void setStatusStage(int stageComplete, int colorOn ) {
    for (int i = 0; i < statusStage.size(); i++) {
        ImageView ss = statusStage.get(i);
        Drawable dr = DrawableCompat.wrap(ss.getDrawable());
        DrawableCompat.setTint(dr, colorOn);
        print("stage Complete:" + stageComplete+", "+i);
    }
}
```

Is the way to setTint different now?
What do I need to change in my codes to get it to work for the new version?

The appcompat version with the bug.

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you've missed to call `setImageDrawable()` there.

```
public void setStatusStage(int stageComplete, int colorOn ) {
    for (int i = 0; i < statusStage.size(); i++) {
        ImageView ss = statusStage.get(i);
        Drawable dr = DrawableCompat.wrap(ss.getDrawable());
        DrawableCompat.setTint(dr, colorOn);
        print("stage Complete:" + stageComplete+", "+i);
        ss.setImageDrawable(dr); //this part
    }
}
```

I also suggest you to use `setTintList()` instead of `setTint()` to represent states.

Comment: The bug persists with ss.setImageDrawable(dr);  this bug just occurs with 23.2.1, but not the earlier versions.